# Select Single Record if ID/Name is Duplicated

Tags: t-sql, select, duplicates

This seems like a really simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out right now...

Here is a simplified view of the data that I am fetching from my current stored proc:

```
ID     Name         Class     Desc
---    -----        ------    -----
84     Calvin J.    2B
53     Fred D.      3B
53     Fred D.      ADJ       Change/Correction
47     Mary F.      3A
47     Mary F.      ADJ       New Product
09     Donald M.    ADJ       Cancelled
21     Richard G.   ADJ       Bad Debt
21     Richard G.   ADJ       Cancelled
```

I need to modify my procedure to select only one record per individual. If a person has an adjustment, I only want to select the record with the adjustment and disregard the other record. Based on the above, this is the result set that I am trying to return:

```
ID     Name         Class     Desc
---    -----        ------    -----
84     Calvin J.    2B
53     Fred D.      ADJ       Change/Correction
47     Mary F.      ADJ       New Product
09     Donald M.    ADJ       Cancelled
21     Richard G.   ADJ       Cancelled
```

Help please!

**UPDATE**

I just realized that there is an additional requirement for this query; if there are two adjustments where one has a description of "Bad Debt" and the other "Cancelled", the record with the "Cancelled" description needs to be selected (see updated data above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Class, [Desc]
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, Class, [Desc],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID
                           ORDER BY CASE WHEN Class = 'ADJ'
                                         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
  FROM Table1
) A
WHERE rn = 1
```

It looks scarier than it really is. The inner query contains an extra column computed with `ROW_NUMBER()`. What this does is number your rows, starting over at 1 for each distinct `ID` (specified in the `PARTITION BY`). The `ORDER BY`, which tells `ROW_NUMBER()` how to order the rows, is a case statement saying that rows with `Class = 'ADJ'` should come before all other rows. Then at the end we grab only rows numbered 1. The result is selecting the ADJ row if there is one for that `ID`, or the regular row otherwise.

**Edit in response to updated requirements**
If you have additional prioritization criteria then you can add those into the `ORDER BY`, just like you would `ORDER BY` in a regular query. Often it's helpful to execute just the inner query without filtering down to `rn = 1` so you can see exactly how row numbers are being assigned.

Here's the updated query that should satisfy your new requirement:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Class, [Desc]
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, Class, [Desc],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID
                           ORDER BY
                             CASE WHEN Class = 'ADJ'
                                  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                             CASE WHEN [Desc] = 'Cancelled'
                                  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
  FROM Table1
) A
WHERE rn = 1
```

[See it in action here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71463/2)

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for your response. But this still doesn't make sense to me. If I've specified an rn of 0 for the rows with class = 'ADJ' and am selecting rn = 1 in my where clause, I will never see them in my result set because as you stated, "we grab only rows numbered 1".

Comment: Good question - the 0 or 1 is not actually the rn. `ROW_NUMBER()` starts at 1 for each `ID` and counts 2,3,4, etc. The 0 or 1 is telling `ROW_NUMBER()` how to order the rows, e.g. if there's a row with ADJ then it'll come before a row without ADJ and therefore be numbered 1.

Comment: Chad, according to the explanation you've given, your solution should work but unfortunately I am still not getting the desired records.